# How to create Text Field with boxes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

How can I achieve something like this in Flutter with ease? Do I have to create several text fields for each box and put them in a row?
I want the user to type in a number just like we type OTP in boxes in apps.

EDIT:
Suppose it's a seven-letter word and the user has to drag letter one by one in appropriate boxes and according to that text field updates how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 5):

There are available Flutter packages that can be used for this kind of input fields:

1. `pininput` => [pininput](https://pub.dev/packages/pinput)
2. `pin_code_fields` => [pin_code_fields](https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields)

Comment: This looks good, I updated the question with one more use case, can you please check that as well?

Comment: You would need to tweak the package and maybe add the proposed functionality using `Draggables`. @HarshitAgrawal

Comment: It would be difficult to have the drag target on point, I guess.

Comment: Maybe, Maybe not. It's still worth trying. @HarshitAgrawal

Comment: If my answer helped you with the problem specified in your original post, please accept it. If not, provide more detail as to why it does not. @HarshitAgrawal

Comment: Yes, your answer is good :) Just waiting if someone could propose a better solution to the edited version as well :)